# Trying to use negative binomial distribution with a linear parameterization V = mu(1 + phi) in brms in r

Tags: r, rstan, glmmtmb

Looking to see if anyone has been able to set up a negative binomial distribution with a linear parameterization V = mu(1 + phi) (Hardin & Hilbe 2007) in the brms package in r?

I want it to correspond to the nbinom1 from glmmTMB, the default negbinomial from brms corresponds to nbinom2 from glmmTMB, the quadratic parameterization (Hardin & Hilbe 2007), V = mu(1 + mu/phi) = mu + mu2/phi. I think I need to make a custom family in brms but I haven’t used this package much and wasn’t able to figure it out. I need to use brms so that I can incorporate phylogeny into my analyses which I can’t do in glmmTMB.

Comment: take a look at https://zenodo.org/record/2639887#.X2j9kJV7nd4 and `vignette("brms_customfamilies")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the advice, I am trying to use the glmmTMBphylo function but I keep receiving the same error message when trying to run the example from the pdf.

glmmTMB_fit <- glmmTMBphylo(phen~cofactor+(1|sp), data=datG , phyloZ=phyloZ
 , phylonm = “sp”, doFit=TRUE, dispformula = ~1 , REML = FALSE)
Error Message:
Error in namedList(nobs = nrow(data.tmb$X), respCol, grpVar, family, contrasts,  : 
  object 'sparseX' not found

Any idea what is causing this? Thanks.

Comment: yeah, things are a little bit out of date/bit-rotted.  The development branch here might work better: https://github.com/wzmli/phyloglmm/tree/mli_devel (`remotes::install_github('wzmli/phyloglmm@mli_devel')`)